# What is the default timeout for Task.Wait

Tags: c#

I have created a web application that uses Task.Wait. Soon after I used it my application slowly came to a crawl about 30 days later. I never found out why but I am suspecting it is the Task.Wait method that never time out if the remote server never response. Just wanted to know if Task.Wait is executed will it wait forever it remote server never response?

Comment: May I ask what you're using `Task.Wait` on?

Comment: Task.Wait is uploading a file to aws s3 and updating the database.

Comment: Why aren't you asynchronously waiting on it with `await`?

Comment: I am using .net 4.0. I cannot upgrade the project

Comment: You don't need to. All you need is to use the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source from [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,045a746eb48cbaa9), this if the code from `Task.Wait()` :

```
public void Wait()
{
#if DEBUG
    bool waitResult =
#endif
    Wait(Timeout.Infinite, default(CancellationToken));

#if DEBUG
    Contract.Assert(waitResult, "expected wait to succeed");
#endif
}
```

So, the timeout is `Timeout.Infinite`!

Comment: To prevent confusion for new developers, I think I would mention that the conditionals are not present in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Wait` waits forever if you don't specify a timeout. Specify the timeout when you start the task. For example, APIs doing HTTP requests usually allow you to configure a timeout.

> my application slowly came to a crawl about 30 days later

You probably should ask a new question about that with details about the problem. The `Task.Wait` is not the problem, though. If anything it's the task itself. Not the waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use the overloads for Task.Wait? As I understand it Task.Wait will wait for forever. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `Task.Wait` by default will wait indefinitely.

> Type: System.TimeSpan A TimeSpan that represents the number of
>   milliseconds to wait, or a TimeSpan that represents -1 milliseconds to
>   wait indefinitely.

That is what the Microsoft Developer Network states for the method.  It also indicates that the thread will wait for one of the following:

> - The task completes successfully.
> - The task itself is canceled or throws an exception. In this case, you    handle an AggregateException exception. The
>     AggregateException.InnerExceptions property contains details about
>     the exception or exceptions.
> - The interval defined by timeout elapses. In this case, the current    thread resumes execution and the method returns false.

The documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public bool Wait(
     TimeSpan timeout
)
```